# "serverless deploy" doesn’t work with –aws-profile option and no error to debug

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

I'm trying to deploy serverless with narrow IAM permission specified below.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudformation:Describe*",
                "cloudformation:List*",
                "cloudformation:Get*",
                "cloudformation:CreateStack",
                "cloudformation:UpdateStack"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-central-1:<accid>:stack/lambda-dev-dep-test*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudformation:ValidateTemplate"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::lambda-dev-dep-test*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::lambda-dev-dep-test*/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:DescribeLogGroups"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:eu-central-1:<accid>:log-group::log-stream:*"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:DeleteLogGroup",
                "logs:DeleteLogStream",
                "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
                "logs:FilterLogEvents",
                "logs:PutRetentionPolicy"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:GetRole",
                "iam:PassRole",
                "iam:CreateRole",
                "iam:DeleteRole",
                "iam:DetachRolePolicy",
                "iam:PutRolePolicy",
                "iam:AttachRolePolicy",
                "iam:DeleteRolePolicy"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::<accid>:role/lambda-dev-dep-test*-lambdaRole"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "apigateway:GET",
                "apigateway:POST",
                "apigateway:PUT",
                "apigateway:DELETE"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:apigateway:eu-central-1::/restapis"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "apigateway:GET",
                "apigateway:POST",
                "apigateway:PUT",
                "apigateway:DELETE"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:apigateway:eu-central-1::/restapis/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "lambda:GetFunction",
                "lambda:CreateFunction",
                "lambda:DeleteFunction",
                "lambda:UpdateFunctionConfiguration",
                "lambda:UpdateFunctionCode",
                "lambda:ListVersionsByFunction",
                "lambda:PublishVersion",
                "lambda:CreateAlias",
                "lambda:DeleteAlias",
                "lambda:UpdateAlias",
                "lambda:GetFunctionConfiguration",
                "lambda:AddPermission",
                "lambda:InvokeFunction"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:lambda:*:<accid>:function:lambda-dev-dep-test*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "lambda:UpdateEventSourceMapping",
                "lambda:CreateEventSourceMapping",
                "lambda:GetEventSourceMapping"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcs"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "events:Put*",
                "events:Remove*",
                "events:Delete*",
                "events:Describe*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:events::<accid>:rule/lambda-dev-dep-test*"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I run this with --aws-profile switch the process returns after "presumably" after assumeRole with no error or any other trace. 
I do not see any events in Cloudwatch and Cloudtrail as well. So basically stuck at this point. any help appreciated

```
ssekar@NB279:~/ssa/data_engg/serverless/examples/lambda_dev_dep_test$ sls deploy -r eu-central-1 --aws-profile lambda-deployment
Serverless: Load command config
Serverless: Load command config:credentials
Serverless: Load command create
Serverless: Load command install
Serverless: Load command package
Serverless: Load command deploy
Serverless: Load command deploy:function
Serverless: Load command deploy:list
Serverless: Load command deploy:list:functions
Serverless: Load command invoke
Serverless: Load command invoke:local
Serverless: Load command info
Serverless: Load command logs
Serverless: Load command login
Serverless: Load command logout
Serverless: Load command metrics
Serverless: Load command print
Serverless: Load command remove
Serverless: Load command rollback
Serverless: Load command rollback:function
Serverless: Load command slstats
Serverless: Load command plugin
Serverless: Load command plugin
Serverless: Load command plugin:install
Serverless: Load command plugin
Serverless: Load command plugin:uninstall
Serverless: Load command plugin
Serverless: Load command plugin:list
Serverless: Load command plugin
Serverless: Load command plugin:search
Serverless: Load command config
Serverless: Load command config:credentials
Serverless: Load command rollback
Serverless: Load command rollback:function
Serverless: Invoke deploy
Serverless: Invoke package
Serverless: Invoke aws:common:validate
Serverless: Invoke aws:common:cleanupTempDir
Serverless: Packaging service...
Serverless: Invoke aws:package:finalize
Serverless: Invoke aws:common:moveArtifactsToPackage
Serverless: Invoke aws:common:validate
Serverless: Invoke aws:deploy:deploy
Serverless: [AWS sts 200 0.584s 0 retries] assumeRole({ RoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::<acc id>:role/SLS_LAMBDA_DEPLOYMENT_ROLE',
  RoleSessionName: 'aws-sdk-js-1547472606934' })
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Also can't invoke the function.